# bind mount in /etc/fstab, to add suid to subdirectory

Tags: linux, mount, fstab

I have succeeded in using mount to do it.

```
sudo mount -o bind dir dir && 
sudo mount -o remount,bind,suid dir
```

It takes two calls to `mount`. I could not get it to work in less. In any case the manual says that it would take two mount-syscalls.
**However**, I can not work out what to put into `/etc/fstab`.

Here is what I have tried.

```
/home/system/dir /home/system/dir none bind
/home/system/dir /home/system/dir none remount,bind,suid
```

and

```
/home/system/dir /home/system/dir none remount,bind,suid
```

Comment: Pardon my stupid question : Why do you need this to be set as part of the fstab ? (vs as part of some init script or udev rule I mean)

Comment: @MC68020 it just seemed simpler. If it can not be done, then yes I should use a script.

Answer (score 0):

I propose a syntax workaround using a single `/etc/fstab` entry to trigger the intended behavior for the bind mount which else won't trigger for `suid` (but would have for `nosuid`). For the impatient, see directly the last line of the answer.

- `/etc/fstab` by [*systemd*](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html#fstab) at boot and by *mount* later won't support duplicate entries

  *systemd* converts each entry into a mount unit. I guess having two units with the same name will cause problems. *mount* itself will have the same problem: can't distinguish two entries with the same name in `/etc/fstab` so will probably only the first, but one could expect a few different behaviors anyway.

  So attempting to handle this with *two* entries in `/etc/fstab` appears difficult.
- the *mount* command (alone or done with *systemd*) handles fine only the reverse case.

  When specifying a "negative" option such as `nosuid` to a bind mount, a recent enough *mount* command (or also *systemd* in case it wasn't *mount*) correctly issues two [`mount(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages-dev/mount.2) system calls, the second using an additional `MS_REMOUNT` flag. When specifying only "positive" options (which translates by a lack of flag in the system call), a single mount system call is issued, even if the intent was to revert a previous "negative" option.

  When specifying an other option that would trigger this 2 system calls behavior, such as `bind,nodev` , additional "positive" options (such as `suid` with `bind,nodev,suid`) are also embarked in the second mount system call (by the mere absence of the flag for the opposite) and this works correctly for `suid` like in this strace example:

  ```c
  743790 mount("/home/system/dir", "/home/system/dir", 0x563792444220, MS_NODEV|MS_BIND, NULL) = 0
  743790 mount("none", "/home/system/dir", NULL, MS_NODEV|MS_REMOUNT|MS_BIND, NULL) = 0
  ```

  The lack of `MS_NOSUID` in presence of `MS_REMOUNT` sets back the mountpoint as `suid`. This also means that all additional non-default options set on the parent mount must be explicitly written back for the additional bind mount or they will disappear. Here not specifying the `suid` option will still remount the bind mount *suid* since in both cases this translates by the absence of a `MS_NOSUID` flag in the 2nd mount system call. An option triggering this 2nd system call must still be present or it won't be issued at all.

As I guess OP's intent is to run rootless containers in this place, an innocuous option should be used that still triggers this behavior. The only candidates I could find in [`mount(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages-dev/mount.2#Additional_mount_flags) were `MS_NOATIME` or `MS_NODIRATIME` and `MS_RELATIME`, the last being today's default and most certainly already present.

> From Linux 2.4 onward, some of the above **flags are settable on a
> per-mount basis**, while others apply to the superblock of the mounted
> filesystem, meaning that all mounts of the same filesystem share those
> flags. (Previously, all of the flags were per-superblock.)
>
> The **per-mount-point flags** are as follows:
>
> - Since Linux 2.4: `MS_NODEV`, `MS_NOEXEC`, and `MS_NOSUID` flags are settable on a per-mount-point basis.
> - Additionally, since Linux 2.6.16: `MS_NOATIME` and `MS_NODIRATIME`.
> - Additionally, since Linux 2.6.20: `MS_RELATIME`.
>
> [...]
>
> Since Linux 2.6.16, `MS_RDONLY` can be set or  cleared  on  a
> per-mountpoint  basis  as  well as on the underlying filesystem
> superblock.
>
> [...]

So in the end an entry triggering today the intended effect can be:

```
/home/system/dir    /home/system/dir    none    bind,relatime   0 0
```

Simply restating `relatime` will trigger the 2nd mount system call and allow to change back to `suid`. With this case, when `/home` has flags `rw,nosuid,relatime`, `/home/system/dir` will have flags `rw,relatime` meaning it handles as usual *setuid* binaries and nothing else changed.

But for consistency, documentation/comprehension and to be proof against future change/improvement, better state explicitly the intended `suid` too:

```
/home/system/dir    /home/system/dir    none    bind,relatime,suid  0 0
```